# ASP.NET MVC 5 Getting Resource Not Found Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an older version of an application (MVC4) deployed on Windows Server 2008 R2 and all works fine. I recently upgraded some libraries and it uses MVC5 so I tried to deploy it but I keep getting "404 Resource Not Found" on the server each time I try to load the page. Running the application locally is OK but whatever is going on the server is rather strange.

There is some sort of routing issue going on but I cannot pin point the exact problem.

webconfig as follows:

```
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />       
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
```

All the Controllers sit in a separate Class Library so namespace is used:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "Application.DefaultController" } );
```

Any ideas on how to check for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from Magnus didn't resolve my problem, it pointed me in the direction towards Nuget.

I updated the asp.net.mvc library to 4.0.0.1 then I right clicked on the web application project and went to Manage Nuget Packages.

In there I went to the Updates option, then clicked 'Update All'

This updated all the libraries and then everything finally worked on the server!

You'd think that this update method should have been applied first even on the local side but for some reason the application still worked locally without updating these references/libraries.

Comment: I still think I answered your question: "Any ideas on how to check for the problem? i.e. What is it trying to route to on the server?"

Comment: Well the glimpse didn't work. When you set it on, then try to load the application, nothing happens. Since the application doesn't even load, glimpse didn't load, so it wasn't a route problem.